# insert an item as a leaf node binary tree

Tags: data-structures, insert, binary-tree

I am having problem writing recursive formulation in python code to insert an item (binary string going from '0000' to '1111' or decimal 0 to 15) as leaf node of a binary tree. It means the tree grows upwards with every insertion and root changes after every insert. Here is the original problem

[specification](http://pastebin.com/sfgjbqcL)

I am having hard time making recursive formulation of the problem as the tree structure changes completely after inserting a new item. Here is an example of the insertion pattern A=0000, B=1111, C=0001, D=0010

[Page1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIcbn.jpg)

[Page2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i3KH.jpg)

How to find a common pattern to code this problem?

Comment: Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: "I need some advice" is a hard question to answer. What do you actually need help with? What is the problem with your code? How does the result differ from what you expect? What have you tried to fix it? (That last one is really important.) [ask]

Comment: @jbapple post updated again

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/54671/755

Comment: We're not going to go poring through multiples pages of poorly formatted text and hand-drawn diagrams. Please read [ask] and formulate your question in a [mcve].

Comment: @jbapple  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36166004/prefix-tree-type-and-insertion  Please point out formatting issues if any

Comment: @D.W. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36166004/prefix-tree-type-and-insertion Please point out format issues if any